# Not able to send message to hostpage using messageParent from outlook dialog box

Tags: dialog, outlook-web-addins

Not able to communicate from dialog box to the host page.

in the page opened in the dialog box, called Office. Initialize() and Office. onReady() functions,
and on button click need to send information back to parent window.

tried sending using below.

Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({messageType: "dialogClosed"}));

But not able to receive any event in the host page.

Please help me in solving this.
Thank you.

**Edit**:

Am checking in both outlook desktop and outlook web

In the dialog box console am able to see messageParent method but not receiving any call to the host page

**OS** : windows 10

**Outlook desktop version**: 16.0.13901.20436 64-bit

**Browser and version**: Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**parent window code snippet**:

```java
var dialog
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {height: 30, width: 20},
function (asyncResult) {
dialog = asyncResult.value;
dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,  function(arg){
    var messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    if (messageFromDialog.messageType === "dialogClosed") {
        dialog.close();
    }
});
});
```

**dialog box code snippet**:

```js
    <script>
         Office.initialize = function (reason) {
};
    </script>
    
    <script>
        Office.onReady(function (_ref) {
    var host = _ref.host;
    console.log("In on ready function")
    console.log(Office.context.ui)
});
    </script>


  function closeWindow1() {
        var messageObject = {messageType: "dialogClosed"};
        var jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(messageObject);
        console.log(Office.context)
        console.log(Office.context.ui)
        Office.context.ui.messageParent(jsonMessage);
        console.log(Office.context.ui.messageParent)
        console.log("Called messageParent method")
        }
```

**logs in the console**:

```
Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
In on ready function
OSF.DDA.UI.ChildUIaddHandlerAsync: ƒ ()messageParent: ƒ ()removeHandlerAsync: ƒ ()__proto__: Object
Office.context
OSF.DDA.OutlookContext {contentLanguage: "", displayLanguage: "en-US", touchEnabled: false, commerceAllowed: true, host: "Outlook", …}
Office.context.ui
OSF.DDA.UI.ChildUI {messageParent: ƒ, addHandlerAsync: ƒ, removeHandlerAsync: ƒ}
ƒ (){var b=OSF._OfficeAppFactory.getHostFacade()[OSF.DDA.DispIdHost.Methods.MessageParent];return b(arguments,a)}
Called messageParent method
```

Comment: Are you seeing this on Outlook desktop, Outlook on the web and the OS (Mac, Windows) are you seeing this on? Please also include Outlook version, and OS version if you are running Outlook desktop.  For Outlook on the web, what browser are you using?  Including the code snippet on where you are calling messageParent, error in console logs and also the code on the parent could also be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  Thank you for the reply, edited the description with the required information, Please look into this.

Comment: Hi @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT could you please help us solve this issue.

Thank you in Advance.